# Find dominant number(number that repeat at least n /2 times)

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Homework:

**Write a program that asks a user to type number n then the program asks the user to input n numbers.The program needs to find a dominant number in a list.The dominant number is one who is repeating at least n/2 times in the list.**

My idea is to create a counter that at the start is 0.If a counter is = or > n//2 we add that number to the list.But this idea doesn't work as I thought.

Code:

```
numbers = []
n = int(input("Type number: "))

for i in range(n):
    numbers.append(int(input("Type number: ")))

print(numbers)

counter = 0
dominant = []

for e in numbers:
    for i in range(n):
        if i == e:
            counter += 1
            if counter >= n // 2:
                dominant.append(i)
print(dominant)
```

**P.S. There is nothing said if there is no dominant number so we will skip that part.**

Comment: "But this idea doesn't work as I thought."—Please describe the problem you are having in more detail.

Comment: Can you edit your question and describe a problem?

Comment: What does "is repeating at least n/2 times in the list" mean? How many times does 2 repeat in [2, 2] -- once or twice? If "repeats n times" means "appears n+1 times" then you can use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_majority_vote_algorithm . Otherwise, you have to use more mundane methods (for example using a `collections.Counter` and then simply finding the element that appears the most).

Comment: `[(x, count)] = collections.Counter(numbers).most_common(1)` gives you the most-common element and the number of times it appears. Note that as you've written the question there may be two dominant numbers, for example in [1, 2, 1, 2] where both 1 and 2 appear 4/2 times.

Comment: "What does "is repeating at least n/2 times in the list" mean?", it means if we have 4 numbers dominant number is one who is repeating at least 2 times.n in the first input is how many numbers we input.
Didn't learn collections.Counter yet, is there any other easier way?

Comment: The problem is  I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
brojevi = []
n = int(input("Koliko brojeva zelite da unesete? "))

for i in range(n):
    brojevi.append(int(input(f"Unesite {i+1}. broj: ")))

print(brojevi)

for e in brojevi:
    brojac = 0
    for j in brojevi:
        if e == j:
            brojac += 1
    if brojac >= n//2:
        print(e)
        break
```